# Change "Apply Discount Code" font color at check out

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to change the "Apply Discount Code" font color at check out.

Any suggestions would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

in your theme css file add below class and change color code what you want to:

```
.checkout-payment-method .discount-code #block-discount-heading span {
    color : color-code;
}
```